# What happens when 1st instruction is at $100 and avr is powered up?

Tags: avr

my question is about AVR:A programmer puts first opcode at address $100.what happens when avr microcontroller is powered up?

Answer (score 0):

The AVR starts executing instructions according to the specifications in its datasheet.  You need to read the datasheet to understand what it will do, but usually it starts executing instructions at address 0 of program memory or at the beginning of a the bootloader section in program memory if the BOOTRST fuse is enabled.

If you want more details on what exactly would happen when the AVR executes from invalid parts of program memory, I would need to know what AVR you are using, what your fuse settings are, and what values are stored in the program memory that will be executing.

Comment: Thanks.This question is from the book,"AVR Microcontroller and Embedded Systems : Using Assembly and C 1 Edition  (English, Paperback, Muhammad Ali Mazidi, Sarmad Naimi, Sepehr Naimi)",chapter 2. Since I am at chapter 5,I don't know about bootloader,fuse etc.

Comment: The most likely answer to your question is that when the AVR starts up it will execute the dummy/non-existent instructions at the beginning of flash one at a time until it reaches the instruction at 0x100 and starts running your program.  However, I still can't say for certain if that is true unless you provide *all* the information I requested.